# Form edit for input file

Tags: php, mysql, web, crud, edit

I am making edit data form. Then in the edit form, there are 3 input file types (image). So the problem is when I update 1 file on one of the input file types, the other input file type updates as well and unlink the previous data in the database, so the column is empty.

So I want to make this edit form, when I update 1 file, the other file does not change. Only the one that is being updated should change and the other should remain unchanged.

All help and answers would be much appreciated. Thank you
Here is the code for `edithotel.php`

```
<?php
    include "koneksi.php";

                $id=$_POST['idhotel'];
                $namahotel=$_POST['namahotel'] ;
                $alamat=$_POST['alamat'] ;
                $notelp=$_POST['notelp'] ;
                $gambar1=$_FILES['gambar1']['tmp_name'];
                $gambar2=$_FILES['gambar2']['tmp_name'];
                $gambar3=$_FILES['gambar3']['tmp_name'];
                $nama_file1 = $_FILES['gambar1']['name'];
                $nama_file2 = $_FILES['gambar2']['name'];
                $nama_file3 = $_FILES['gambar3']['name'];
                $tempat_gambar1= 'file/hotel/gambar1/'.$nama_file1;
                $tempat_gambar2= 'file/hotel/gambar2/'.$nama_file2;
                $tempat_gambar3= 'file/hotel/gambar3/'.$nama_file3;
                $latitude=$_POST['latitude'] ;
                $longitude=$_POST['longitude'] ;
                $qr=mysql_query("select * FROM tbhotel WHERE idhotel='$id'");
                $r=mysql_fetch_array($qr);
                $tempat_foto1 = 'file/hotel/gambar1/'.$r['gambar1'];
                $tempat_foto2 = 'file/hotel/gambar2/'.$r['gambar2'];
                $tempat_foto3 = 'file/hotel/gambar3/'.$r['gambar3'];

                //$ccc = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbhotel WHERE idhotel='$id' ");
                //$z = mysql_fetch_array($ccc);

                //upload gambar

                if (isset($_POST['simpan'])){
                    if($gambar1 != 'kosong'){
                            $d1 = 'file/hotel/gambar1/'.$r['gambar1'];
                            unlink ("$d1");
                            move_uploaded_file ($_FILES['gambar1']['tmp_name'], "file/hotel/gambar1/".$nama_file1);
                            //echo '<script>alert("DATA BBB DIUBAH");location="hotel.php";</script>';
                            $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE tbhotel SET namahotel ='$namahotel', alamat = '$alamat', notelp = '$notelp' ,  gambar1='$nama_file1', latitude ='$latitude' , longitude ='$longitude'  where idhotel='$id'") or die (mysql_error());
                    }

                     if($gambar2 != 'kosong'){
                            $d2 = 'file/hotel/gambar2/'.$r['gambar2'];
                            unlink ("$d2");
                            move_uploaded_file ($_FILES['gambar2']['tmp_name'], "file/hotel/gambar2/".$nama_file2);

                            $sql2 = mysql_query("UPDATE tbhotel SET namahotel ='$namahotel', alamat = '$alamat', notelp = '$notelp' ,  gambar2='$nama_file2', latitude ='$latitude' , longitude ='$longitude'  where idhotel='$id'") or die (mysql_error());
                    }


                     if($gambar3 != 'kosong'){
                            $d3 = 'file/hotel/gambar3/'.$r['gambar3'];
                            unlink ("$d3");
                            move_uploaded_file ($_FILES['gambar3']['tmp_name'], "file/hotel/gambar3/".$nama_file3);

                            $sql3 = mysql_query("UPDATE tbhotel SET namahotel ='$namahotel', alamat = '$alamat', notelp = '$notelp' ,  gambar3='$nama_file3', latitude ='$latitude' , longitude ='$longitude'  where idhotel='$id'") or die (mysql_error());

                    }


                            if ($sql) {
                                //jika  berhasil tampil ini
                                echo '<script>alert("DATA BERHASIL DIUBAH");location="hotel.php";</script>';
                            } else {
                                // jika gagal tampil ini
                                echo '<script>alert("DATA GAGAL DIUBAH");location="formedithotel.php";</script>';
                            }
                }


?>
```

And here is the code for `editform.html`

```
<form name="edithotel" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="edithotel.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="demo-form2" data-parsley-validate class="form-horizontal form-label-left">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" for="last-name">Nama Hotel</label>
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <input type="text" id="namahotel" name="namahotel" value="<?php echo $result['namahotel']; ?>">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" for="last-name">Alamat</label>
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="alamat" name="alamat" ><?php echo $result['alamat']; ?></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" for="last-name">No Telp</label>
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <input type="text" id="notelp" name="notelp" value="<?php echo $result['notelp']; ?>">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">Gambar 1</label><br>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <img src="file/hotel/gambar1/<?php echo $result['gambar1']; ?>" width='80' height='60'/>
      <input type="file" id="gambar1" name="gambar1" value="kosong">
    </div>
  </div><br>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">Gambar 2</label><br>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <img src="file/hotel/gambar2/<?php echo $result['gambar2']; ?>" width='80' height='60'/>
      <input type="file" id="gambar2" name="gambar2" value="kosong">
    </div>
  </div><br>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">Gambar 3</label><br>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <img src="file/hotel/gambar3/<?php echo $result['gambar3']; ?>" width='80' height='60'/>
      <input type="file" id="gambar3" name="gambar3" value="kosong">
    </div>
  </div><br>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" for="last-name">Latitude</label>
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <input type="text" id="latitude" name="latitude" value="<?php echo $result['latitude']; ?>">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" for="last-name">Longitude</label>
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <input type="text" id="longitude" name="longitude" value="<?php echo $result['longitude']; ?>">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="ln_solid"></div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-md-offset-3">
      <button type="submit" name="simpan" class="btn btn-success">Update</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Format your code please, this is unreadable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need check $nama_file1 and others on empty.

```
if($gambar1 != 'kosong' && !empty($nama_file1)){
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the first code after every image field and obviously you will need to change to name of hidden field for every row.

Then in your query you will need to check that

```
<input type="file" id="gambar1" name="gambar1" value="kosong">
<input type="hidden" name="gambar1_current" value="<?php echo $result['gambar1']; ?>">

if (isset($_POST['gambar1']) !="") {
    $image = $_POST['gambar1'];
}else{
$image = $_POST['gambar1_current'];
}
```

And do this for all 3 images and insert $image variable in database.